# Python fuzzer, threading anomaly

Tags: python, multithreading, ftp, fuzzing

I am developing a simple FTP fuzzer in Python. I first test for the USER command and then for post authentication commands. The problem is that after the USER fuzz requests, the thread for all the other commands (one at a time) is not started at all. On the hand if I start the fuzz requests for all the other commands directly without fuzzing USER before (i.e. commenting that section of code), it works fine. It seems to be a problem with the starting/stopping of threading. The winappdbg api is used to start a new instance of the FTP server for each loop, which should be closed with join() if no crash occurs. Any idea?

```
    t = threading.Thread(target=simple_debuggerFTP)
    t.start()
    ftpfuzzer =  FtpFuzz()
    i = 2
    while True:
        # get fuzz heuristic code
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)


        try:
            # send fuzz request
        except:
            print "[!] Target server doesn't respond any more, check crash logs..."
            break

    t.join()

    # fuzz loop for all other commands
    commands = ["PUT", "TEST", "MKD", "CWD"]
    for cmd in commands:
        t = threading.Thread(target=simple_debuggerFTP)
        t.start()
        ftpfuzzer.reset()
        i = 2
        while True:
           # get fuzz heuristic

            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)


            try:
               # send fuzz request
            except:
                print "[!] Target server doesn't respond any more, check crash logs..."
                break

    t.join()
```